# WiFi verbose logging at Android L Developer Options

Tags: android

There is "Enable WiFi verbose logging" option in Developer Options of Android L Preview.

Does anyone know how to use it?

Comment: Why is this question considered too broad? It's an option in the developer's menu of an Android device that isn't explained anywhere.

Comment: @djunod have no idea, why it's too broad, but hope to get answer anyway.

Comment: It's been a year. Surely now somebody knows ;) And I think the question is pretty clear and totally legitimate. I want to know where I can see the logs when I enable this. I just did and it does not show any hint about the location of these logs.

Comment: Not enough, but this is what I found. "Enable Wi-Fi Verbose Logging: this command increases Wi-Fi logging level, shows per SSID RSSI in Wi-Fi Picker"

Read more http://en.androidmir.org/katya/515/